# is there a design theory that says column + row can resolve any design

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am facing difficulty aligning points with text in a way that centers both the points and the center line. My goal is to achieve perfect alignment in both rows and columns. I have tried various approaches, but none seem to work as expected. Can someone please guide me on the best method to achieve this? I am using rows and colums

```
Colum {
    Row{
        Icon(point)
        Text(“requirement payment”)
    
    Icon(VLine) 
    Row{
        Icon(point)
        Text(“requirement payment”)
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `ConstraintLayout`.

```
ConstraintLayout {
    val (icStep1, icStep2, contentStep1, contentStep2, linkLine) = createRefs()

    Icon(point, Modifier.constrainAs(icStep1) {
        top.linkTo(parent.top)
        start.linkTo(parent.start)
    })
    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(contentStep1){
        top.linkTo(icStep1.top)
        bottom.linkTo(icStep1.bottom)
        start.linkTo(icStep1.end)
        end.linkTo(parent.end)
    }) {
        Text(A) // eg. AED 3626
        Text(B) // eg. Required payment
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(16.dp)
            .width(1.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Blue)
            .constrainAs(linkLine) {
                top.linkTo(icStep1.bottom)
                start.linkTo(icStep1.start)
                end.linkTo(icStep1.end)
            }
    )

    Icon(point, Modifier.constrainAs(icStep2) {
        top.linkTo(linkLine.bottom)
        start.linkTo(icStep1.start)
        end.linkTo(icStep1.end)
    })

    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(contentStep2){
        top.linkTo(icStep2.top)
        bottom.linkTo(icStep2.bottom)
        start.linkTo(icStep2.end)
        end.linkTo(parent.end)
    }) {
        Text(C)
        Text(D)
    }
}
```

It looks like a lot of code but it's really only the constraints. It's still mostly Rows, Icons and Texts